# Формирование текста sql запроса

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

Текст sql запроса (`fullsqlcondition`) формируется в зависимости от нажатого чекбокса input (`$input = $('input[name="available.all"]')`) в jquery коде

```js
$input = $('input[name="available.all"]');
let editfullsqlcondition = "";
let fullsqlquery = "";

if $(input).on("change", function() {
    if $input.checked {
      pickupavailable = "and goods.deliveryvalue=1";
      editfullsqlcondition += pickupavailable;
      /*select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue = 1*/

    } else {
      if editfullsqlcondition.includes("goods.deliveryvalue=1", 0) {
        if editfullsqlcondition.endsWith("goods.deliveryvalue=1") {
          fullsqlcondition = editfullsqlcondition.slice(0, editfullsqlcondition.length - " and goods.deliveryvalue=1".length);

        }
        else {

          fullsqlcondition = editfullsqlcondition.slice(0, editfullsqlcondition.indexOf("goods.deliveryvalue=1 and ",

            0)) + editfullsqlcondition.slice(editfullsqlcondition.length - editfullsqlcondition.indexOf("goods.deliveryvalue=1 and ", 0) - editfullsqlcondition.length,

            editfullsqlcondition.length)
        }
      }

    }
  }
  console.log(fullsqlcondition);
);
```

Каким образом можно передать текст sql запроса при обращении к базе данных (php код, если возможен javascript или jquery код, то тоже напишите)?

Answer (score 0):

В не правильно подходите к построению запроса.

1. Запрос не формируется на клиенте. (Есть опасность инъекции запроса.) (что если просто подменить значение `fullsqlcondition` на `drop Database`)
2. На сервер передаются параметры формы (значения выбранных инпутов: текстбоксов,чекбоксов, радио .....). В последеющим на сервере формируется запрос и возращяется ответ на клиент.

**UPD**

Пример [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164884/ajax-post-and-get-checkbox-value)

```
.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/checkbox.php',
    data: { foton : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

    success: function(data) {
        $('#message').html(data);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Но ведь событие change для чекбокса описывается в js, а каким образом на сервер передаются параметры формы (пункт 2, php файл) (я знаю только, что поведение их описывается в js) (распишите подробнее, чтобы разговор был предметным, а то 2-й пункт показался слишком общим)

Comment: .ajax запросом отправляете параметер и значение параметра (ключ - значение) на сервер (endpoint) который обработает ваши параметры, обратится к базе и вернет значение

Comment: а почему пару ключ - значение, а не просто переменную?

Comment: Когда передадите переменную, возникнет желание передать ещё одну ротом ещё ... А как их различать на сервере если не вносить протокол

Comment: мое представление остановилось на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255195/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-jquery-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: В любом случае там будет объект $(this).serialize() ключ значение

Comment: объясните мне последний момент (и я приму ответ), а что если мне требуется передать  `<a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>`, а именно текст этой гиперссылки (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255195/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-jquery-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0), то как будет выглядеть код

Comment: $(".nestedblock").text()

Comment: что в data будет указываться? (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255195/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-jquery-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: { paramName : $(".nestedblock").text()}

Comment: 1. а почему не просто `$(".nestedblock").text`? 2. И что конкретно указывается вместо paramName на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255195/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-jquery-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0 (мне практики не хватает)

Comment: потому что text() это функция, и её нужно вызывать

Comment: 2. Напишите что угодно. Про100 на сервере будите ждать под этим именим там значение

Comment: а в качестве paramName что должно быть указано на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255195/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-jquery-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: попробуйте будет field1

Comment: а где обрабатывается щелчок на checkbox-е input (если на сервере, то не понятно как оформить обработку выбора на php коде)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120889/discussion-between-frontendbeginner-and-aziz-umarov).