# Файловая структура, структура файлов сайта и разделение кода

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Есть сайт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В зависимости от выбранного пункта левого бокового меню (список категорий товара) меняется правое боковое меню (список характеристик категории товаров) (с помощью технологии ajax). По выбору пунктов правого бокового меню, а именно чекбоксов, отображается список товаров (пустая центральная часть) - с помощью технологии ajax. Подскажите какова структура файлов сайта (html, javascript, php, jquery) и файловая структура.
Что должно быть включено в html файл, javascript и php? С одной стороны должно быть как на [Обработка выбора чекбокса на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256215/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5), но с другой должно быть как на [Формирование текста sql запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256152/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0). До некоторых пор я считал правильной логику

```html
<html>

/* Описание элементов интерфейса */

/* Jquery код - обработка щелчков на элементах интерфейса, ajax код */ 

</html>

<?php

    /* Обработка переменных $_POST */
    /* Передача ответа клиенту */
?>
```

но на [Формирование текста sql запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256152/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0) мне написали, что так как я считаю неправильно. Где

```html
/* Описание элементов интерфейса */

<div class="leftmenu">
  <ul id="sidemenu">
    <li>
      <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
/* Jquery код - обработка щелчков на элементах интерфейса, ajax код */ <
script >
  $('.nestedblock').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax.php',
      data: {
        valuemenuitem: $(this).innerText
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.rightmenu').html(data.msg);
      }
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```js
$valuemenuitem = @$_POST['valuemenuitem'];

/*
... 
     Обработка переменных $_POST
     Передача ответа клиенту 
*/
```

Comment: Нам надо вам архитектуру придумать?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper я просто плохо понял разделение кода в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256152/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256215/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5

Comment: @mepihindeveloper особенно не понятно как устроены файлы, задействованные в ajax?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper я уточнил вопрос.

Comment: В РНР файлах которые обрабатывают аякс запросы, просто не должно быть никакого HTML кода. Вот и всё, если в этом вопрос.

Comment: @Ипатьев вопрос в том, что если js не должен формировать текст sql запроса, то каким образом будет происходить передача данных от клиента к серверу?

Comment: @Ипатьев что, как и где должно передаваться серверу?

Comment: Я не понимаю этого вопроса. Это полная бессмыслица. Судя по всему у тебя принципиально превратное представление о каком-то из используемых терминов. Данные посылает не клиент на сервер, а наоборот, **сервер - клиенту**. Клиент максимум может послать на сервер **несколько переменных**, на основе которых сервер сформирует SQL запрос, выполнит его, получит данные из БД, и отправит на клиент

Comment: А, главное, к *файловой структуре* это всё не имеет вообще никакого отношения.

Comment: @Ипатьев а что конкретно неверно на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256152/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0 (укажите конкретные ошибки в коде)?

Comment: Это шутка? Там уже есть подробный ответ с указанием на все ошибки. Ну или точнее ошибка там ровно одна - SQL не формируют на клиенте. Что тут непонятно-то?